# IBM Watson Text-to-Speech pronounces sentence-ending point after custom word

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm using the WDC Text-to-Speech service, and have the below case:

I'm using a customized model, based on fr-FR_ReneeVoice, to customize the way some words are pronounced. One of the words is "ONT", which is translated to

```
<phoneme alphabet="ibm" ph=".o.En.te"></phoneme>
```

When this word occurrs at the end of a sentence (such as "Trouvez votre ONT."), the TTS service explicitly pronounces the sentence-ending dot (such as "Trouvez votre ONT **point**"). If I remove this dot, it messes up the pronunciation of the next sentence, as there is no sentence break.

How should this be handled? The documentation does not mention any limitations or ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same case and cannot replicate the issue that you see.  Can you run this curl command and report back what you see for the translation for the word ONT?

curl -k -u username:password   -X GET "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/customizations/customID?alphabet=spr"

I get the following:
   "words": [{
      "translation": "`[.2o.0En.t1e]",
      "word": "ONT"
   }],

In above curl command, replace with your username, password and customization ID.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: "words": [
 {
  "translation": "`[.1Ef.t0e.t0e.0aS] ",
  "word": "FTTH"
 },
 {
  "translation": "`[.2i.p0e.t0e.v1e]",
  "word": "IPTV"
 },
 {
  "translation": "`[.2E.l0o.1Es]",
  "word": "LOS"
 },
 {
  "translation": "`[.2o.0El.t1e]",
  "word": "OLT"
 },
 {
  "translation": "`[.2o.0En.t1e] ",
  "word": "ONT"
 },
 {
  "translation": "`[.p2e.0o.1En]",
  "word": "PON"
 },
 {
  "translation": "`[.0E.m1y]",
  "word": "mu"
     }]

Comment: I see that there is an extra space in the translation for word 'ONT' in your model which is causing the problem that you observed.  Was this word added a while ago (say, before December)?  Can you add the same word again in case the issue is due to this being an older custom model?  Because as I said before, I tried adding the same word and could not replicate the problem.  I see spaces in other words too, such as 'FTTH', so if re-adding the word fixes the issue with 'ONT', you should do the same for all words where you see the extra space in the translation part (after the ']').

Comment: Deleted the word and re-added it using the exact same command I used the first time, but this time it removed that extra space and the issue no longer occurs. Thanks @tony.